# Should I stub the model in Factory girl or in the spec file while testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, mocking, stubbing

Almost every spec file I come accross I end up writing stuff like:

```
  before :each do
    @cimg = Factory.build :cimg_valid
    @cimg.stub(:validate_img).and_return true
    @cimg.stub(:validate_img_url).and_return true
    @cimg.stub(:save_images).and_return true
    @cimg.stub(:process_image).and_return true
    @cimg.stub(:img).and_return true
  end
```

I mean, the model I get from Factory.build is completely valid. But if I don't stub that stuff it saves things in the filesystem, and validates stuff I'm not testing...

What I mean, I think it would be cleaner to do something like this:

```
  before :each do
    @cimg = Factory.build :cimg_for_testing_tags
  end
```

If stubbing within the Factory is even possible.

What is the proper way to stub the model?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In recent versions of factory_girl you have an after_build callback, so I believe you could define your factory like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :cimg_for_testing_tags do

    ... # Factory attributes

    after_build do |cimg|
      cimg.stub(:validate_img).and_return true
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

After factory_girl 3.3.0, the syntax has changed to following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :cimg_for_testing_tags do

    ... # Factory attributes

    after(:build) do |cimg|
      cimg.stub(:validate_img).and_return true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: But *should I do it*? Or should I stub it in the spec file?

Comment: I think that if you are repeating yourself lots of times, having a general stub make sense in this case, just make sure that :cimg_for_testing_tags has a parent factory that is not stubbed for situations in which you want to test the actual behavior.

Comment: This is an awesome technique. I've found myself struggling with a solution for this kind of situations. Thanks @fkreusch !

Comment: This no longer works. As of the latest rspec this will result in the failure `"Using 'stub' from rspec-mocks' old ':should' syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated."` Unfortunately if you switch to using the new rspec `allow()` syntax you run into a different problem because FactoryGirl does not include RSpec's methods: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'allow' for #<FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner:0x007f95469cc0d8>`. Does anyone know a solution to this which works with the latest versions?

Comment: You can do `def cimg.validate_img; true; end` and effectively stub it out without rspec.

Comment: @Jazz There's a way to use the allow syntax. See my answer.

Answer (score 35):

@fkreusch's answer works great until you use the new RSpec `expect()` syntax (3.0+)

Putting this into `rails_helper.rb` works for me:

```
FactoryBot::SyntaxRunner.class_eval do
  include RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods
end
```

In the OP's example, you can now do:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :cimg_for_testing_tags do

    ... # Factory attributes

    after(:build) do |cimg|
      allow(cimg).to receive(:validate_img) { true }
    end
  end
end
```

Credit: github.com/printercu, see: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/703#issuecomment-83960003

Comment: Doing what is described here now issues the following error (FactoryGirl v4.7.0):
```The use of doubles or partial doubles from rspec-mocks outside of the per-test lifecycle is not supported. ```

Comment: @jsears I was encountering that error because my `rails_helper.rb` was running `FactoryGirl.lint` in a `before(:suite)` block, and stubs can't be set up there. I solved the issue by wrapping the lint call in `RSpec::Mocks.with_temporary_scope { ... }`.

Comment: Note that `FactoryGirl` is now `FactoryBot`, so those two names should change in your example.

Answer (score 5):

A factory should produce "real world" objects therefore it's a bad practice (and error prone) to change behaviour (i.e. stub) in a factory.

You can do

```
let(:user) instance_double(User, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user))

before do
  allow(user).to receive(:something).and_return('something')
end
```

and if your `before` clause gets too big you may want to extract it to a separate method or create a mock child class that overrides methods you want to stub.

Answer (score 3):

You might also consider using [FactoryGirl#build_stubbed](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/use-factory-girls-build-stubbed-for-a-faster-test).